# How to use Room @Relation with join condition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have two entities PackEntity and UserEntity. I want to retrieve the pack and its associated user with the following

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM packs LEFT JOIN users WHERE pack_id = :packId AND packs.is_active AND users.is_active")
    fun getPackWithUser(packId: String): Flow<PackWithUserEntity?>

    data class PackWithUserEntity(
        @Embedded
        val packEntity: PackEntity,
        @Relation(parentColumn = "user_id", entityColumn = "id",)
        val userEntity: UserEntity?
    )
```

I am pretty sure left join there is doing nothing as this test fails

```
@Test
fun testGetPackWithUser_IfActivePackInActiveUser_ReturnPackWithNullUser() = runTest {
    val user = testUser(id = "0U1", isActive = false)
    val pack = testPack(packId = "0P1", userId = user.id, isActive = true)
    userDao.insert(user)
    packDao.insert(pack)

    val result = packDao.getPackWithUser(packId = pack.packId).first()
    assertThat(result?.packEntity).isEqualTo(pack)
    assertThat(result?.userEntity).isNull() // Because user is not active
}
```

QN: How can i join the two with a condition that users.is_active needs to be true

Answer (score 1):

> I am pretty sure left join there is doing nothing as this test fails

The way that Room works, as you have found, is that with an `@Relation` it retrieves ALL children of the relationship irrespective of SELECT query that appears to limit the children. Room generates it's own query to retrieve the children of a parent.

The solution is to avoid/override Room's handling by splitting the process into the parts that you want.

That is have an `@Query` for retrieving the parent(s) and then have an `@Query` for retrieving the required/selective child(ren) and finally combine them in a function with a body that invokes both queries.

Example:-

Based upon your code then you could have:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM packs WHERE is_active AND pack_id=:packId")
fun getActivePackById(packId: String): PackEntity

@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pack_id = :packId AND is_active")
fun getActiveUsersForAPack(packId: String): UserEntity?

@Transaction
@Query("")
fun getSelectivePackWithUser(packId: String): Flow<PackWithUserEntity> {
    return PackWithUserEntity(getActivePackById(packId),getActiveUsersForAPack(packId))
}
```

- Note the empty query fools room into actually wrapping the processing into a transaction.
- An alternative, more efficient (from a database perspective) approach, would be to process the product of the original query extracting/building the end result. More efficient as only the single query is used.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and it works as expected though I did make some changes to ensure it return the flow that react to changes on both user and packs tables

Comment: I have posted my answer with modifications, can you edit your answer so that I can accept it (You deserved it)

Answer (score 0):

To properly use flow (reactive stream), I modified the @MikeT code to be be like this

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    fun getPackWithUser(packId: String): Flow<PackWithUserEntity?> {
        return getActivePackById(packId).combine(getActiveUserByPackId(packId)) { pack, user ->
            if (pack == null)
                null
            else
                PackWithUserEntity(pack, user)
        }
    }
```